# Failed to create MD5 hash for file entry_debug_unsigned_entry.apk as it does not exist. in DevEco Studio HarmonyOS

Tags: java, antivirus, windows-defender, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I'm trying to build my HarmonyOS app. It was working fine when suddenly windows defender gave me a message that it had found a threat, and directly after I get an error message: `Failed to create MD5 hash for file **'C:\Users\Admin\DevEcoStudioProjects\MyApplication\entry\build\intermediates\shell_output\debug\entry_debug_unsigned_entry.apk'** as it does not exist.`

Comment: If you got solution for question posted, please elaborate your answer with proper information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Disable Windows defender or disable anti-virus if you have any and it working fine.